# how do make edit on viewable to original poster the posts are called 'car' in my app RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<ActionView::Base:0x4cdbb48>
Extracted source (around line #7):

4:     <dd>
5:     <%= car.name %><br />
6:     <%= car.description %><br />
7:     <%= link_to('edit', edit_post_path(@car)) if current_user.cars.include?(@car) %>
8:     <%= link_to "Delete", 
9:     :controller => :car, 
10:    :action => :delete,
```

I am using session[:user_id] = @user.id to track current users login and car.id for the post id, how do I link the two together so that only the original person who posted can view the edit link?? Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personaly, to solve similar problems I've used the devise gem.

Then I make sure I have an association of some sort between the user and car tables (to use your example) and then put a simple erb check to see if they are matching. If they aren't, use the read only view otherwise allow the editable view. The erb check would look something like this.

```
<% if current_user.id = car.owner.id %>
  ...show the editable view... 
<% else %>
  ...show the read only view...
<% end %>
```

If you simply don't want them to see the view if they don't "own" it, you can use a before_filter in your controller to check the user to car relationship and then do the "right thing" based upon your required application requirements. You can forward to an unauthorized action view or simply redirect them to a safe place.

Also, you can simply hide the links or buttons that would lead to the view, but no matter what I'd protect in the controller as well.

I hope this helps a bit...

EDIT: I should say that using the devise gem provides me with total 'user' support out of the box, and then you can relatively easily tailor it to your specific business requirements.

Comment: do I need to install devise gem I am using @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])to track currently logged in user and the controllers are linked car belongs to user and user has many cars etc

Comment: I did 'gem install devise'. It adds some routes "registrations" and "sessions". It will also create the user table migration for a new user table. I always do this first thing on projects I know will need this sort of behavior so I am unsure how to add it late in the game. look here for more information: railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Comment: how would i add that before_filter to check if they owned the car.id before displaying the links? @jaydel

Comment: In your controller: at the top insdie the class do 'before_filter :<method_name>'. Then define that method later on in the class. That method should compare the things of interest. in the method you have access to params, and you can get current_user as well fairly easily, but this part depends upon your implementation of users.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have the logged in user in `@user`, so you could simply do this:

```
<%= link_to('edit', edit_post_path(@car)) if @car.user_id == @user.id %>
```

I recommend using ActiveRecord's associations - they will come in handy in this and other scenarios.

app/models/user.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  ...
end
```

app/models/post.rb

```
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

Then in your view template you could do:

```
<%= link_to('edit', edit_post_path(@car)) if @user.posts.include?(@car) %>
```

For clarity, I highly recommend using the model name for variable names whenever possible e.g. `@post` instead of "@car" for instances of the Post model.